# Dangling foreign keys for dependent entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I use DbContext.

Look at these two variants of code:

```
var context = new MyEntities();
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var item = context.Items.OrderBy( i => i.Id).First();
var oCtx = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var relationshipManager = oCtxc.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(item);
```

AND this one:

```
var context = new MyEntities();
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

var item = context.Items.OrderBy( i => i.Id).First();
context.Entry(item);    
var oCtx = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var relationshipManager = oCtxc.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(item);
```

The only difference is the call `context.Entry(item);`

I have differen results.
In the first case `relationshipManager.Relationships.Count` equals 1
In the second one - 5

Item has one foreign key property and RelationshipManager creates dangling key for it. That's Ok.

*Shouldn't ObjectContext query for the keys of dependent entities of the item which has relation 'One to Many?'*

That's definitely what `DbContext.Entry()` does behind the scenes but I though this is alredy implemented by ObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as ObjectContext queries for dependencies' keys but initially does nothing for null values (no dependent items - EntityReference.EntityKey = null).
When ProxyGeneration is enabled any navigation property access triggers the generation of dangling keys for such null values.
Without proxies new relationships for null values are added when `DbContext.Entry()` is called.

I do not know whether it's DbContext's feature or ObjectContext has the same behavior. Need to check...